# iOS share sheet/extension not fading status bar

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io, ios-sharesheet

I have a share sheet/extension that, for some reason, is not fading the status bar (even though it fades the rest of the screen). I have included an image to demonstrate the issue. I simply want the entire screen to fade, including the status bar. In the past, I've had a similar issue with UIAlertControllers not fading the status bar.

[image: image of status bar not being faded]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was seeing this as an app-wide issue, I started looking in my AppDelegate instead of the individual view controllers. I found a function, `setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.white)`, called on app launch that appeared to be the cause.

```
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
    guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return }
    statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}
```

Frankly, I'm not sure why I had written this, but removing it appears to solve the issue entirely.

Answer (score 2):

i think its better to tweak it only necessary `UIViewControllers` (when needed) by using,

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.default  //dark content
}
```

or on the parenting `UINavigationController`, to avoid above bugs you have experienced.

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps in an earlier iOS version (or due to another, now changed, config file), the status bar was displaying as black/dark on all ViewControllers, and so I just put this in the AppDelegate and forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you presenting a UIAlertController with animated: set to true? I'm not able to reproduce this issue using the buo.showShareSheet() method:

```
 let buo = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: "referrer/\(UUID().uuidString)")
        buo.title = "Test"
        buo.contentDescription = "Test"

        let lp: BranchLinkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
        lp.feature = "referral"
        lp.addControlParam("user_id", withValue: UUID().uuidString)

        buo.showShareSheet(with: lp, andShareText: instructionString, from: self) { (params, success) in

        }
```

Comment: Yes, in the cases where I'm seeing this issue when using a UIAlertController, I am doing "animated:true". I just figured out the issue; please see my answer for details.